# Multiclassing Shaman/Invoker

Tags: dnd-4e, multi-classing, shaman

I'm playing an Eagle Shaman that took the 'acolyte of divine secrets'-feat to multiclass to Invoker.

> Acolyte of Divine Secrets [Multiclass Invoker]
>
> Prerequisite: Wis 13
>
> Benefit: You gain training in Religion. Choose a 1st-level invoker at-will attack power.
> You can use that power once per encounter. In addition, you can wield invoker implements.

If I chose an At-will that has "Can be used as a basic ranged attack" rider, can I make use of that? Or does it lose that property once it is an encounter power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes!

You can use the power as a ranged basic attack. There's no reason that it would lose that property.

## But!

You can still only use it once per encounter. Specific overrides general. The feat says you can use it once per encounter, and that's that. It still counts as a ranged basic attack for that one use, but if you were trying to get a shiny new at-will power, this won't quite get you there.